# Calculate the percentage from a melt dataframe

Tags: r

This is the melt dataframe which has the groups

```
data.frame(group = c(1,1,2,2), trend = c("twitter", "twitter", "amazon", "twitter")
```

How is it possible to create a new data frame based on the trend per group

```
data.frame(group = c(1,1,2,2), trend = c("Twitter", "Amazon", "Twitter", "Amazon") value = c("100%", "0%", "50%", "50%"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr you can achieve your goal.

```r
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,2,2), trend = c("twitter", "twitter", "amazon", "twitter"))

(data2 <- data %>%
    group_by(group, trend) %>%
    count() %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(n = n/sum(n)*100))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
  group trend       n
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     1 twitter   100
2     2 amazon     50
3     2 twitter    50
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` and `proportions`:

```
proportions(table(x), 1)
#   trend
#group amazon twitter
#    1    0.0     1.0
#    2    0.5     0.5
```

Or more in the desired format:

```
as.data.frame(proportions(table(x), 1)*100)
#  group   trend Freq
#1     1  amazon    0
#2     2  amazon   50
#3     1 twitter  100
#4     2 twitter   50
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(group = c(1,1,2,2), trend = c("twitter", "twitter", "amazon", "twitter"))
```